# A subgroup which is generated by $W$-marginal subgroups is itself $W$-marginal

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

There is a conclusion on $W$-marginal subgroups of a group:

> A subgroup which is generated by $W$-marginal subgroups is itself $W$-marginal.

Here, $W$ is a set of words. In a group $G$, a normal subgroup $N$ is $W$-marginal in $G$ if $w(g_1, \cdots, g_{i-1}, g_ia, g_{i+1}, \cdots, g_r) = w(g_1, \cdots, g_{i-1}, g_i, g_{i+1}, \cdots, g_r)$ for all $g_i \in G$, $a \in N$ and all words $w(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_r)$ in $W$. This is equivalent to the requirement: $g_i \equiv h_i$ mod $N$ $(1 \leq i \leq r)$, always implies that $w(g_1, \cdots, g_r)=w(h_1, \cdots, h_r)$.

But if I

> Let $W= \{ x^2 \}$, $G=D_4$ (or sometimes denoted $D_8$), the dihedral group of order $8$. $G$ can be written as $$\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^4=1,abab=1\rangle= \{1, b, b^2, b^3, a, ab,ab^2, ab^3\}.$$ Let $N_1=\{ 1, a, b^2, ab^2 \}$, $N_2=\{ 1, ab, b^2, ab^3 \}$. Then $N_1 \trianglelefteq G$, $N_2 \trianglelefteq G$. Moreover, since both $N_1$ and $N_2$ consist of elements of order $1$ or $2$, $N_1$ and $N_2$ are $W$-marginal subgroups of $G$. $N_1$ and $N_2$ generate $G$, but $G$ is not $W$-marginal, as $b\in G$ and $b^2 \neq 1$.

This contradicts with the conclusion.

I am eager to know where is wrong, and why the conclusion is all right. Thank you very much!

(Page 62, Derek J.S. Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, GTM 80)

Comment: $N_2$ is not W-marginal: $a\equiv b\mod N_2$ and yet $1=a^2\neq b^2$.

Comment: @Steve D: Thank you very much for pointing out. I considered only the case when one of the two elements equalled to $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that usually we define the (full) marginal subgroup by requiring that insertion of $a$, *on either side*, not affect the value of the word. This does not require the assumption that the subgroup be normal ahead of time. With the added assumption that your elements form a normal subgroup, this is equivalent, of course, since $Ng = gN$ as sets.

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a group. The full marginal subgroup associated to $w=x^2$ is the set of central elements of exponent $2$; i.e., $w^*(G) = \{ g\in Z(G) \mid g^2 = 1\}$.

*Proof.* Let $g\in Z(G)$ be of exponent $2$. Then for all $x\in G$, $w(xg) = (xg)^2 = x^2g^2 = x^2$ (since $g$ is central and of exponent $2$), and likewise $w(gx) = (gx)^2 = g^2x^2 = x^2$. Thus, $g\in w^*(G)$.

Conversely, let $g\in w^*(G)$. Then $1 = w(1) = w(1g) = g^2$, so $g$ is of exponent $2$. Now let $x\in G$. Then  we have that $w(gx) = w(x) = w(xg)$, hence $gxgx = x^2$. Thus, $gxg = x$, so $gx = xg^{-1} = xg$. Thus, $g$ centralizes $x$, so $g\in Z(G)$. **QED**

(More generally, the full marginal subgroup associated to $w(x) = x^n$ is the set of central elements of exponent $n$).

In particular, a sugroup of $G$ is marginal relative to $w=x^2$ if and only if it consists of central elements of order $2$. However, you are only checking that the elements be of order $2$.

(*Added.* It seems that you were only checking for elements such that $w(g)=1$; while this is necessary for $g$ to lie in the marginal subgroup, it is not sufficient.)

Thus, note that neither $N_1$ nor $N_2$ are $w$-marginal, since they both contain noncentral elements. The only $w$-marginal subgroups of the dihedral group of order $8$ are $\{1\}$ and $\{1,b^2\}$.

---

As to the proof that a subgroup generated by (normal) marginal subgroups is itself marginal: let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be normal $W$-marginal subgroups of $G$, where $W$ is a set of words. Then $N_1N_2$ is a normal subgroup, and is the subgroup generated by $N_1$ and $N_2$. Let $w\in W$ be a word in $k$ letters, let $n_1\in N_1$, $n_2\in N_2$, and let $g_1,\ldots,g_k\in G$. We need to show that 
$$w(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1},g_i(n_1n_2),g_{i+1},\ldots,g_k) = w(g_1,\ldots,g_n).$$
Since $N_2$ is $W$-marginal, we have
$$w(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1},g_i(n_1n_2),g_{i+1},\ldots,g_k) = w(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1},g_in_1,g_{i+1},\ldots,g_n).$$
Since $N_1$ is $W$-marginal, we have
$$w(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1},g_in_1,g_{i+1},\ldots,g_n) = w(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1},g_i,g_{i+1},\ldots,g_n).$$
Thus, the required equality holds.

That is, for every $x\in N_1N_2$, for every $w\in W$,
$$w(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1},g_ix,g_{i+1},\ldots,g_k) = w(g_1,\ldots,g_n).$$
Inductively, the result holds for any finite family of marginal subgroups. If $\{N_i\}$ is an arbitrary family of marginal subgroups, and $x\in \langle N_i\rangle$, then there is a finite set $\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$ such that $x\in N_{i_1}\cdots N_{i_k}$, and thus $x$ is itself marginal by the finite case.

Thus, a subgroup generated by $W$-marginal subgroups is also $W$-marginal.

For some more on marginal and verbal subgroups, see [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26243/center-commutator-duality/26248#26248).

Comment: Thank you very much. But I think there are still some points I don't understand. As you have pointed out, when the words are of the form $x^n$, the marginal subgroup is in the center. Does this hold when there are other types of words in $W$? Moreover, would you please give me some hints on the proof of the first statement "A subgroup which is generated by $W$-marginal subgroups is itself $W$-marginal"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShinyaSakai: Not every marginal subgroup is necessarily central. The marginal subgroup associated to the word $[[x,y],z]$, for example, is the *second center*, which in a nilpotent group will properly contain the center. As for the proof of the statement, isn't it immediate? Use the verbal definition, not the congruence one, to show that if $g$ and $h$ are marginal elements, then so is $gh^{-1}$.

Comment: Splendid answer! Thanks you very much!