# Duality of $Z(G)$ and $[G,G]$ in representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, duality-theorems

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26243/center-commutator-duality) and its many wonderful answers illustrate many faces of the duality of $Z(G)$ and $[G,G]$, the centre/ commutator duality of a group.

I was thinking about its manifestation in group representations. We might as well look at a finite group $G$ and its classes of irreducible representations $\hat{G}$, and some possible candidates might be \begin{equation}
d_{\alpha}=\operatorname{degree}(\alpha)
\end{equation}  and \begin{equation}
n_{d}=\#\{\alpha\in\hat{G}:d_\alpha=d\}.
\end{equation}Some evidence might be contained in

> $d_{\alpha}$ divides $\#G/Z(G)$ for all $\alpha\in\hat{G}$.

So the larger $Z(G)$ is, the more *commutative* $G$ is, the smaller $d_\alpha$ is.
On the other hand,

> $n_1=\#G/[G,G]$.

So the larger $[G,G]$ is, the less *commutative* $G$ is, the smaller $n_1$ is.

So, I am wondering whether these can be made precise. And are there other manifestations of the $Z(G)/[G,G]$-duality in group representations?

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think those are pretty precise.