# Generalisation of abelianisation using representation theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Every $1$-dimensional representation of $G$ over $k$ factors through $G^{\mathrm{ab}} = G/[G, G]$, and every finite abelian group has a faithful representation over $k$.
Taken together, these simple facts show that one can characterise the abelianisation $G^{\mathrm{ab}} = G/[G, G]$ of $G$ as the smallest quotient of $G$ such that every $1$-dimensional representation of $G$ factors through it.

Let $G_n$ be the smallest quotient of $G$ such that every $n$-dimensional representation of $G$ over $k$ factors through $G_n$. Clearly $G_1 = G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ and I've read that if $G$ has a generating set of size $m$ then $G_m = G$, i.e. $G$ has an $m$-dimensional faithful representation.
What does $G_2$, or what do the $G_n$ look like in general? Can they be characterised in a different way? What do they tell us about $G$?

Comment: By "largest quotient" do you maybe mean largest normal subgroup that you quotient by?

Comment: @MPos Thanks, I've fixed it

Comment: So this essentially asks about the intersection of the kernels of reps of a given degree. While not quite the same, you may be interested in my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/284225/2538 which has some results about the intersection of irreps not of a given degree

Comment: The post is now cross-listed and receives attention in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460598/generalisation-of-abelianisation-using-representation-theory