# What is the relationship between Inner Automorphism group and Commutator subgroup? Why are they both about commutativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group, derived-subgroup

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group.

If $G$ is Abelian, the commutator subgroup $[G,G]=\{ghg^{-1}h^{-1}|g,h\in G\}$ is *trivial*; otherwise, the commutator subgroup is not trivial and there is the Abelianisation $\mathrm{Ab}(G)=G/[G,G]$.

Also, if $G$ is Abelian, then the centre is itself or $\mathrm{Z}(G)=G$. Thus, its Inner Automorphism group $\mathrm{Inn}(G)\cong G/\mathrm{Z}(G)$ is *trivial*.

I can see that if $G$ is not Abelian, then its Inner Automorphism group will not be trivial, but I do not know what happens next.

Are there some interesting relationships between $[G,G]$ and $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$? Still, why are commutators and inner automorphisms both about commutativity of one group?

Thanks.

Comment: Inner automorphisms are "about commutativity" in so far as the inner automorphism group is isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$, so it's about the center. For the "duality" of commutator subgroups and center, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26248/742).

Comment: ... whatever "about" means in this situation. And without knowing what it means, I've voted to close.

Comment: Note: $[G,G]$ is **not** defined to be the set of elements of the form $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$. It is the *subgroup generated* by all such elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $[G,G]$ is trivial then $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=e$ and so $ghg^{-1}=h$. So for every $g$ and $h$ we see that $h$ is stabilized by conjugation. Said another way, the group of inner automorphisms is trivial.