# Is there an analogue of the abelianization of a group for nilpotent groups?

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups

If $G$ is an arbitrary group we denote its abelianization as $G^{ab} := \frac{G}{[G,G]}$, where $[G,G]$ is the commutator. As an abelian group it is characterized by the following universal property:

> Let $\pi : G \to G^{ab}$ be the quotient morphism. If $\varphi : G \to H$ is an morphism between $G$ and an abelian group $H$, then there is a unique morphism $\hat{\varphi} : G^{ab} \to H$ such that $\varphi = \hat{\varphi}\circ\pi$.

In a sense the abelianization is the abelian group that is closest to $G$. I wonder if there is a solution for the analogous universal property, but with nilpotent groups instead of abelian. (Or, perhaps only over nilpotent groups of class $n$ for fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the abelianization being the case $n=1$)

Comment: You have to fix the class $n$, otherwise free groups provide a counter-example to the existence of a universal nilpotent quotient.

Comment: These are answers to the question. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well, one could argue that you answered the question and then turned it into a question by appending "no?". But despite what the rules may say about comments, they are useful in practice for providing quick hints and suggestions, which is what you are doing.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that, although not all groups have a largest nilpotent quotient, many do, including all finite groups. There is an algorithm due to Charles Sims that computes and proves correctness of the largest nilpotent group of a group defined by a finite presentation if it exists. So in particular it can be used to verify that the presentation defines a nilpotent group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For any **variety of groups** $\mathfrak{V}$ (a class of groups that is closed under subgroups, arbitrary products, and homomorphic images), given a group $G$ there is a *verbal subgroup* $\mathfrak{V}(G)$ with the property that:

1. $\mathfrak{V}(G)$ is normal in $G$ (in fact, fully invariant);
2. $G/\mathfrak{V}(G)\in \mathfrak{V}$;
3. Any morphism from $G$ to a group in $\mathfrak{V}$ factors through $G/\mathfrak{V}(G)$.

The subgroup $\mathfrak{V}(G)$ is generated by all values of words that are laws of the variety $\mathcal{V}$. See the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26248/742).

The class of all nilpotent groups of class at most $c$ is determined by the law
$$[[\cdots[[x_1,x_2],x_3]\cdots],x_{c+1}]$$
(that is, a group $G$is nilpotent of class at most $c$ if and only if every evaluation of that word at elements of $G$ yields the identity element). The corresponding verbal subgroup is also known as the **$(c+1)$st term of the lower central series of $G$** and plays the same role relative to nilpotent groups of class at most $c$ as the commutator subgroup (second term of the lower central series) relative to abelian groups (nilpotent groups of class at most $1$).

However, there is no similar subgroup for the class of *all* nilpotent groups. You can take the intersection of all terms of the lower central series, which will have properties 1 and 3 above, but need not have property 2, so it cannot be called a "nilpotenciation" of $G$. Similar things happen with "solvable of length at most $n$" (use the $n$th term of the derived series) vs. "solvabilization".

(Some groups *may* have a subgroup satisfying 1, 2, and 3 relative to "all nilpotent groups"; if the terms of the lower central series stabilize, then that subgroup is the one you want. E.g., all finite groups necessarily have this property; for instance, the "nilpotenciation" of $S_3$ is its abelianization).